# Magento admin login page showing "whoops our bad" (404 error )

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have tried many solutions which are given in Stack Overflow and it's not working anymore. My Magento version is 1.5. Why am I getting this issue after I tried all the solution for admin?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have used **index.php** in url before admin route name.This is needed if url rewrites are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

index.php before /admin or any suffix you have

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

To edit this file use 
    sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf command

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After this run command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

IF STILL ADMIN SHOW 404 NOT FOUND, Add htaccess file

1) Add .htaccess at root of magento

Answer (score 0):

Copy the index.php and .htaccess files from /pub/ to your root folder.

Find the below line in the index.php (in the root folder):

require **DIR** . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
and replace it with

require **DIR** . '/app/bootstrap.php';